# How to read abc.com like strings with scanf?

Tags: c

> Im trying to read from stdin something like abc.com but a[0]='\0' after run scanf instead of  'a'. Im using %[^.] to read all character until find a '.'.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    char a[6];
    char b[4];

    int i = scanf("%[^.]%s", a, b);

    printf("%d\n", i);
    
    printf("a: %s\n", a);
    printf("b: %s\n", b);
    
    printf("%c\n", a[0]);
    printf("%c\n", a[1]);
    printf("%c\n", a[2]);
    
    if (a[3]=='\0') puts("why?");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Better to use `fgets()`.

Comment: bernardomadeirarosa, Who or what text suggested an `s` in `"%[^.]%s"`?

Comment: *Always* add a width modifier to `%s` and `%[` conversion specifiers to avoid buffer overflows.  In this case:`scanf("%5[^.]%3s", a, b);` (Which makes it fairly clear that you need to increase the size of the buffers.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying `char b[5];` will get you an output of

```
2
a: abc
b: .com
a
b
c
```

It indicates that you have read 5 characters into `b`, the fifth being the `'\0'` which overwrites `a[0]`. The first one being the `'.'`, which intentionally is the NOT read by the format for `a`. You hence write beyond `b` (which is undefined behaviour and I should stop explaining right now....).
One of the possible behaviours of this UB is that the fifth read character for `b` is written beyond and into the first entry of `a`.